# How would I add a loop cut here

Tags: modeling, topology, geometry

I need to create a complex geometry at one place on my model,

[image: model's topology]

so I would *not* use the *knife* tool I would add loop cuts but it doesn't let me to.

[image]
[image]

I already deleted the faces and created them again but even when I think that the topology of this certain place is alright I still cant't add a single loop throughout all the tube.

**So my Question is: Why is this happening and what would be the best thing for me to do?**